# Macbook Pro Mid 2010 not powering up after smc update

Tags: macbook-pro, power, power-management

Macbook Pro Mid 2010 after SMC update 1.7 shuts down and now by pressing power button front light turning on for a few seconds, optical drive makes it's usual noise but no activity on monitor happens and it's not powering up. Battery and Charger are working fine also resetting the SMC is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same and managed to fix it using this reference:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/22024754#22024754

In summary, this is the fix:

> 1. Disconnect power
> 2. Open MBP and disconnect/remove the battery - close the back cover again
> 3. While power is still disconnected, press and hold the power button for about 5 seconds and then while pressing and holding the power button, connect the power cable to the MBP.
> 4. If you are lucky, your MBP will now power up with the fans blazing at 100% and keyboard backlight will be off.  This seems to be a recovery emergency mode or something.  If you MBP did not power up, try again. If your MBP does not power up then you have a different problem and don’t need to continue the following steps.
> 5. Boot you OSX and go onto the Internet and Download the right SMC firmware version for your MBP from: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237
> 6. Mount/Open the `.dmg` file and copy out the “Firmware” `.pkg` file.
> 7. Use Pacifist or the command line to extract the content of the `.pkg` file.
>      In my case the Apple SMC update had three models firmware in  the `.pkg` file and the correct one for the Mid-2010 15” model was in the folder SMC18 or something.
> 8. Find your correct model firmware for your MBP and copy out the following two files:  `SmcFlasher.efi` and `2010MBP15.smc`  (the `2010MBP15.smc` will be different for other MBP models)
> 9. Copy those two files onto the OSX disk drive to a location that you can remember like `/User/username/Dowloads/smc`  or where ever.
> 10. Google and search for `rEFIt` .  This is a boot loader app the will take over the boot process when you start up your MBP to enable you to go into a shell utility.  Read up on how to install and how to activate the refit utility.  When installed and enabled, the next time you reboot your MBP you will see the utility start up before your OSX boots.
> 11. If you see the `rEFIt` utility start after you rebooted the MBP, use the arrow on your keyboard and select shell and press enter.  The `shell.efi` utility will start to boot in a “DOS” like window and after you see something where it wants to configure or setup something, just press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to cancel that.
> 12. After the `util` booted, you need to first change to your internel disk with the command `fs1:`  that is `F` `S` `ONE` `Colon` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, standing for filesystem 1
> 13. Now you can change to the folder to where you copied the two firmware files like:
>
>     - `cd Users`
>     - `cd username`
>     - `cd Downloads`
>     - `cd smc`
> 14. There are different ways of going to the folder or find the place where you put the files.
> 15. After finding the folder with the two files you can start the update process.
> 16. First need to get the SMC into the right state
>       `SmcFlasher.efi -reset 1`
> 17. Your MBP fans should now quiet down.
>       Lets Flash :-)
>       `SmcFlasher.efi -force -LoadApp 2010MBP15.smc -norestart`
>
> Your SMC should now be flashing with the right version.  Once done, power down the MBP. Power the MBP back on and do a SMC reset and all should be fine now.  You can now connect the battery again and start using your MBP.